# How to Integrate Nautilus with a Repository?

Tags: nautilus, repository, fedora, unsupported-packages

I decided to install an rpm package in Ubuntu using the alien tool. The RPM Package was Bliss OS but it didn't get installed for some reason. If someone knows why please help me. But that's not the reason I've made this post. I thought I'd integrate the fedora repo with nautilus so if I wanted to install any fedora app, I would browse through the packages in nautilus and after locating it, I would copy it to my Downloads folder and then install it with alien. I know I can access the repo from my web browser but it takes time to open and nautilus would just be much quicker. I tried going to Other Locations and then trying the "Connect to Server" Option by entering "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/31/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/" in it but didn't work. I also tried "ftp://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/31/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/" and it kept saying peer has reset the connection. I've added the fedora repo to Ubuntu. Is it safe? And after adding it, how can I install it directly to ubuntu like it is done in fedora-

```
sudo dnf install package_name
```

I googled it many times but all I found was something about integrating Git Repo with Nautilus. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install in Ubuntu like you do in Fedora, then I recommend you to switch distro to Fedora. Both use a fundamentally different package management system. The package management system in use is for some people a reason to choose a certain distribution. I cannot imagine how you were able to add the Fedora repository to Ubuntu. The question "Is it safe" can be answered with certainty with "No". The only thing that can happen here is that you break your system.

The way you describe "integrating nautilus with a repository" suggests that you want to browse files in the repository with nautilus file manager. Nautilus indeed allows to setup network connections through its graphical interface, and supports a number of protocols. You can see the supported protocols clicking the question mark icon in the "Connect to server" field that you see when navigating to "Other locations" in nautilus. The server you want to connect to must, of course, allow you to connect using one of the supported protocols.